# How to execute a function every time a Navigator view controller is loaded?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a second view on my app which is shown with a navigation bar. I'd like to execute a function when this second view opens. But when I open the second view and go back to the main view and reopen the second view, it shows the last change and no new changes. How do I execute a function every time the second view is shown?

Comment: the second view is a UIView or UIVIewController?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just using the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` (or didAppear) method of your second view controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method which loads data in the second view. 
e.g. if you have your data stored in an array, you can do in following way:
- (void)loadDataInSecondView:(NSArray*)inputData
    {
          //Write to logic to load data in second view
    }

And when you present the second view, just call this method with that.

Comment: thanks , i want to reload second view again because all of objects in second view should reopen and create again

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the second controller on the mainView globally.

```
- (void)functionSecondView:(BOOL)isReload {
        // Do something on your second contoller(object values)
         if(isReload) {
            [secondContoller reload];
         }
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondContoller animated:YES];
 }
```

Note: reload function if you want to clear the data on the secondController